# What would cause wear on one side of brake pads n rotor that were replaced not 6mo. ago

Tags: brake-rotor

I have a 2006 Nissan Sentra and replaced both front rotors n brake pads not less than 6mo. Ago. My passenger side was making grinding noise so I took a look at my brakes cause it sounded like metal on metal. When I took my brakes off seen they were gone n my rotor looked worn yet on the drivers side both looked fine. Can you tell me what can cause this?

Comment: I had replaced both rear end wheel brake pads. Less than 3 months the pad on the out side view wore out. (Keep in mind that it was the right side) I replaced them again. I kept checking then week by week, then I noticed that the pad on the left outside view had wore out. How does that even happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've seen this happen when the pads aren't aligned properly, sometimes from a missing shim or retaining spring. Basically the pad and rotor are in constant low grade contact and things wear really quickly as a result.

Comment: When you say shim, do you mean the thin metal pieces that the pads slide into?

Comment: @Cricket yes exactly.. That's what I've heard them called around here.. Not sure if it's an official name or not.

Comment: @Cricket it's usually pretty obvious if the shim alignment is the issue.. You'll see shiny metal where it wasn't before.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that you have a caliper that is stuck or simply not working or a bubble in the brake line/fluid. Bleed the brake line. If the fluid is brown, keep bleeding until it runs clear. If you see bubbles (or the fluid stops coming out for a few seconds) wait until you see all the normal brake fluid come out.

Don't forget to add more brake fluid (and try not let the line run dry, or else you will have to keep bleeding the line until you get those bubbles out).

Tip: I usually push a 3/8" clear vinyl tube over the bleeder screw so that I can better oberve the color of the fluid and see bubbles in the tubing as I bleed the brake line.

If one brake line has brown brake fluid it is getting over heated, probably due to a bad caliper. Bubbles may indicate over heating or a bad caliper as well but then again, maybe not. The brake line itself may be to blame, or there may be a small leak somewhere. Since brake fluid is corrosive to metal, look for any unusually rusty (nissans are notoriously rusty, so look for extra rusty) joints/unions in the brake line.

Comment: I haven't seen any rust. So is that the only way to tell if you have a bad caliper?

Comment: Oh, not by a long shot! The easiest way to check a caliper is to squeeze the piston(s). So you have to take the caliper off the rotor to do that. If one side (like the driver's side) feels more difficult to depress then you have a problem. You should be able to depress them by hand (especially if you open the bleeder screw).

Comment: When I depressed the calipers I put old brake shoe in front of piston n used a clamp but it didn't take much was fairly easy. So could it be something else?

Comment: Yes, it could be a bubble in the line... that's more common than a bad caliper... usually bleeding the brakes fixes your issue... sometimes the caliper is bad.

Comment: My caliper was "stuck" causing brake pad wear as @Cricket described.  I replaced the brake pads and rotor, and in the process of doing so fully compressed the caliper piston.  This appears to have addressed the issue; I've since bleeded the brake lines and have had no problems.

Comment: Since air is compressible, and fluid is not, a bubble usually results in uneven braking/wear.

Comment: Thank you I am going to try n bleed my brakes n pray for the best

Comment: Oh yeah, also- if you open the bleeder valve and it takes a while for brake fluid to come out- that may be your bubble! The valve/screw should be at a high point on the caliper, so that any bubbles inside the caliper will migrate/float up to the screw for bleeding off. So, when you open the valve, the bubble might escape first. I can't really say how long it should take, but the rate of fluid flow might indicate whether you were waiting while air was escaping; but let it keep flowing until you collect at least a couple ounces of fluid. And don't forget to add fresh fluid (under the hood).

Answer (score 0):

I had simillar issue with brakes wear on driver side and passenger side still looks new on my 2003 Corolla. Calliper pins were ok as they slide back and forth freely. So check brake lines and no leaks I already new I had air bubbles in my brake line
How to fix. Jack car on passenger side take out tire, open engine hood and locate brake fluid reservoir, open top cover just so air can escape through, now compress ur calipar piston, go in to car and pump your brakes so the piston moves out again, at this time start engine to release pressure from calipar piston. Note  start car with transmission in neutral or parking position, now compress the piston one more time. Fit in your brake pad. once done , had someone depres brake pedal for you. Hold the rotor with both hands and try to rotate. Note rotor won't move with brakes depressed and will have a slight rotatory movement when brakes released. Fit your tire